# What cipher suites come with Java jdk1.7.0_03, and / or how do I provision my RMI installation with them?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I've been wracking my brain on this problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610217/troubleshooting-java-rmi-client-network-connection-refusal), and suddenly thought to check if ANY cipher suites were available to the RMI Server. So, I put the following code in JUST BEFORE the RMI Registry is started:

```
msg("trustStore: "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
msg("trustStorePassword: "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
msg("keyStore: "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore")); 
msg("keyStorePassword: "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"));
msg("rmi.server.hostname: "+System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname"));msg("supportedCipherSuites: "+System.getProperty("javax.rmi.ssl.client.supportedCipherSuites"));
msg("enabledCipherSuites: "+System.getProperty("javax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledCipherSuites"));
msg("debug: "+System.getProperty("javax.net.debug"));
```

(where msg just sends data via `System.out.println`.)

...And to my horror found that "`supportedCipherSuites`" is `NULL`!

**What?!**

I looked all over creation, "used the google", and haven't yet figured out how I'm supposed to populate my instalation with suitable cipher suites.  ...I'm not looking for much special, just the basic ordinary stuff will do fine!

**Arg!**

**P.S.** Where does the RMI Registry's output from javax.net.debug go? Can't find it anywhere! Thanks....

Comment: Did you install the unlimited strength cryptography policy files?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not explicitly - how do I do that? Back in the day, there was a JSSE download, but I didn't find one today. ...I think that's a part of my stated question, "how am I supposed to populate my installation with suitable cipher suites?" -smile-  Sounds like you could tell me!

Comment: By default the Java installation restricts the encryption strength because of weird American export laws (and this has always been the case). You can download the policy files at http://java.oracle.com (BTW: I am not saying this is the solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the list of supported cipher suites in Oracle JRE 7 in the [SunJSSE provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider): there are two tables for those enabled and disabled by default, respectively.

I wouldn't worry too much about `System.getProperty("javax.rmi.ssl.client.supportedCipherSuites"))` returning `null`: these system properties are for you to make settings, not for the JRE/RMI API to publish its current state. In addition, there is no mention of this system property [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/rmi/ssl/SslRMIClientSocketFactory.html) where `javax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledCipherSuites` is documented.
If you want to use specific cipher suites, set `javax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledCipherSuites`, don't read it.

Getting the `javax.net.ssl.*` properties won't necessarily tell you what the actual used values are (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140199/372643)). For example a `null` `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` will still use the default truststore.

Same for `javax.net.debug`: it's for you to set and the Net/SSL API to use, not the other way around.

Comment: I can't show that you're wrong about "javax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledCipherSuites", however if it is indeed used as you describe then its name is _stupid._ It should be "setCipherSuites" or even just "enableCipherSuites" - that "ed" makes it PAST TENSE. I'd find it beyond odd that the engineers who created the Java SSE would be _that_ unaware of the proper use and meanings of suffixes in english! That said, your answer otherwise appears to be correct, so I'm flagging it as so! -smile- Thank you for your help.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, "-ed" is not just for past tense or preterite, but can be used a noun modifiers almost as adjectives (e.g. "Something is required."), although "something is enabled" and "something has been enabled" could both work, I think. System properties are settings, not methods; an active verb would imply an action there and then, which is not something that system properties are meant to do. Perhaps it's something to ask on http://english.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I like my "drop the d" solution better - that way it's not an action, like set, but a request, as in "please!" -smile- Boy, software would be SO MUCH BETTER if _we_ were the engineers making it! Oh, wait, we ARE, just not _Java_ engineers!